# Sorting table content after loading them

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

In my App the user can follow different groups. My code first checks which groups the user does follow and puts it in an array. After that the code opens each group id and loads every post in it with newPost = importPosts. And after that the post gets inserted to the table. At the same time it also loads the picture of the user asynchronous. Every post has a timestamp.
But the posts don't get sorted after the timestamp. How can I do that? Right now it is totally randomly.

I tried .queryOrdered(byChild: "userTime") but this does not work. It sorts them before the posts from different groups are merged. So after merging them they are again not sorted. The merging is the issue.

I also tried table.sort { $0.newPost.userTime < $1.newPost.userTime } but then it says Contextual closure type '(DataSnapshot, String?) -> Void' expects 2 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body.

```
 var table = [importPosts]()
 var users = [UserModel]()
var dic = [String:[importPosts]]()
static var myArray1: [String] = []
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


func loadFollowedPoi() {
        myFeed.myArray1 = []
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let database = Database.database().reference()
        database.child("user/\(userID)/abonniertePoi/").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                myFeed.myArray1.append(child.key)
            }
            self.postsLaden()
        })
    }
    
    func postsLaden() {
        dic = [:]
        for groupId in myFeed.myArray1[0..<myFeed.myArray1.count] {
            print(groupId)
            
            let placeIdFromSearch = ViewController.placeidUebertragen
            ref = Database.database().reference().child("placeID/\(groupId)")
            ref.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
                guard let dic = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
                let newPost = importPosts(dictionary: dic, key: snapshot.key)
                guard let userUid = newPost.userID else { return }
                self.fetchUser(uid: userUid, completed: {
                    self.table.insert(newPost, at: 0)
                    print(newPost.userTime)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    func fetchUser(uid: String, completed: @escaping () -> Void) {
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("user").child(uid)
        ref.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            guard let dic = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            let newUser = UserModel(dictionary: dic)
            self.users.insert(newUser, at: 0)
            completed()
        }
    }
```

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

...
    var post: importPosts? {
        didSet {
           // print("Kommentare werden geladen")
            guard let _post = post else { return }
            guard let _username = post?.userName else { return }
            guard let _userComment = post?.userComment else { return }
            guard let _userLikes = post?.userLikes else { return }
            guard let _userTime = post?.userTime else { return }
            guard let _kommentarCount = post?.kommentarCount else { return }
            guard let _usergroup = post?.userGroup else { return }
            
            updateCellView(userName: _username, userComment: _userComment, userLikes: _userLikes, userTime: _userTime, kommentarCount: _kommentarCount, usergroup: _usergroup, post: _post)
        }
    }
    var user: UserModel? {
        didSet {
            
            guard let _username = user?.userName else { return }
            guard let _profileImageUrl = user?.profileImageUrl else { return }
            
            setupUserInfo(username: _username, profileImageUrl: _profileImageUrl)
        }
    }
   
}
...
```

```
class importPosts {
    var userName: String?
    ...
    var id: String?
    
    var likeCount: Int?
    var likes: Dictionary<String, Any>?
    var isLiked: Bool?
    
    init(dictionary: [String: Any], key: String) {
        
        userName = dictionary["userName"] as? String
        userID = dictionary["userID"] as? String
        userComment = dictionary["userComment"] as? String
        userGroup = dictionary["userGroup"] as? String
        userTime = dictionary["userTime"] as? Int
        userLikes = dictionary["userLikes"] as? Int
        commentId = dictionary["commentId"] as? String
        placeID = dictionary["placeID"] as? String
        kommentarCount = dictionary["kommentarCount"] as? Int
        userImage = dictionary["userImage"] as? String
        userTimeForArranging = dictionary["userTimeForArranging"] as? Int
        
        id = key
        
        likeCount = dictionary["likeCount"] as? Int
        likes = dictionary["likes"] as? Dictionary<String, Any>
        
        ViewComments.commentIDNew = commentId!
        
        if let currentUserUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
            if let likes = self.likes {
                isLiked = likes[currentUserUid] != nil
            }
        }
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Database:
[image]

Comment: You need to add context: What is `table`? And what is the definition of its content. You have `users` and `table`, but it's unclear why you insert at 0. The calls are async, so there is no guarantee that the callback will occurs in the same call order.

Comment: Thanks for asking. I added some more code. Sorry if the question did not contain every needed detail.

Answer (score 1):

Without a bit more context and view of the database structure, it's a bit difficult to provide code to solve your issues. That being said, I think there are a few things to consider.

My understanding is you are fetching posts from users included in each group individually. Is this correct? To fetch a sorted array from your database, you'd likely need to fetch all posts where `post.groupId is in groupIds` where `groupIds` is your array of desired `groupId`.

If you're going to stick with the fetch + append to existing array approach, the naive method is to sort the resulting array every time you append new posts. Assuming `table` is your array of posts:

```
self.fetchUser(uid: userUid, completed: {
                    self.table.insert(newPost, at: 0)
                    print(newPost.userTime)
                    self.table = self.table.sorted(by: { $0.userTime > $1.userTime }) 
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I already tried that way but I get the error: "Contextual closure type '(DataSnapshot, String?) -> Void' expects 2 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body" on the line:  "ref.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in". And I just can't solve that issue.

Comment: Hmm, seems like your closure is expecting two parameters. Might be an unrelated issue.

Try to see what `string` is with `(snapshot, string) in print(string)`

Comment: Yes and I don't know why.

Comment: Can you access the parameter to check its value? I'll try recreating the issue in playground shortly.

Comment: Not in a place where I can run playgrounds just yet and can't recall the exact code from memory, but give a try:

`self.table = self.table.sorted {(firstPost:Post, secondPost:Post) -> Bool in return firstPost.userTime > secondPost.userTime}`

Comment: Can you please check again? I added some more code. Sorry if the question did not contain every detail.

Comment: Sure, I'll take another look shortly. But first, I noticed your table sort might be causing the issue:

If you're sorting with `table.sort { $0.newPost.userTime < $1.newPost.userTime }`, I don't believe `newPost` is necessary here. Rather, `{ $0.userTime < $1.userTime }` should be sufficient.

Comment: I think I solved it. I used this:             ref.observe(DataEventType.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
 instead of this:             ref.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
. I will test it and reply.